# What are the odds of a family of 4 sharing two birthday dates?

Tags: probability

I (the father) and my daughter share one birthday, and my wife and our son share another birthday.

We've always wondered what are the odds of this happening. And specifically, a family, not just 4 random people... which I guess could be the same.

Comment: The probability that two of four people share one birthday, and the other two share a second, different birthday, is (assuming $365$ days a year) $\frac{1}{365}\times\frac{364}{365}\times\frac{1}{365} + \frac{364}{365}\times\frac{2}{365}\times\frac{1}{365} = \frac{3 \times 364}{365^3} \approx 0.0000224566$.

Comment: We pick any set of four people, and order them in any specific sequence—e.g., father, mother, daughter, son.  Then the above analysis breaks it up into two cases: (1) second birthday matches first ($1/365$), in which case the third can be any other day ($364/365$), and then the fourth must match the third ($1/365$); (2) second birthday doesn't match ($364/365$), in which case the third can match either of the first two ($2/365$), and then the fourth must match whichever the third didn't ($1/365$).

Comment: Alternatively, we can select two dates out of the year in $\binom{365}{2} = \frac{365\times364}{2} = 66430$ ways.  Then we can pick two of the people to go to the earlier birthday in $\binom{4}{2} = \frac{4\times3}{2} = 6$ ways, accounting for $66430 \times 6 = 398580$ satisfactory birthday selections.  Altogether, there are $365^4$ ways to choose four birthdays, so the desired probability is $\frac{398680}{365^4} \approx 0.0000224566$.

Comment: @BrianTung Looks like an answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

So a family consists of for people named $A,B,C,D$

There are $365$ birthdays $A$ can have and for each one of those there are $365$ birthdays for $B$ to have and so on.  So the number of possible birthday combinations are $365\times 365 \times 365 \times 365 = 365^4$.

Now for two pairs to have the same birthdays, we have to find who will be the pair the shares.  The options are $A,B$ share and $C,D$ share.  Or $A,C$ share and $B,D$ share.  Or  $A,D$ share and $B,D$ share.  Those are the only $3$ ways.

Now for each of those $3$ are $365$ days that the first pair can have, and $364$ that the second pair can have.  So there $3\times 365 \times 364$ ways to have two pairs share different birthdays.

Assuming each combination is equally likely the probability is

$\frac {3\times 365 \times 364}{365^4} = \frac {3*364}{365^3} \approx 1$ in $44530$.  Very unlikely.

On the other hand, very unlikely things, are very likely to happen... just not that ones you predict.

......

Oh, maybe an easier way to do it.

Your birthday is your birthday.  That's fixed.  The probability that your daughter has your birthday is $\frac 1{365}$.  And the probability your son has your mothers birthday is $\frac 1{365}$.  So the probability that both those thinks occur is $\frac 1{365}\times \frac 1{365}$.

But that's not the only way this can occur.  We could you share your birthday with your daughter.  That's $1$ way.  Or you could share your birthdy with your son.  That's a $2$nd way.  Or you could shore your birthday with your wife.  That's the $3$rd way.

So the probability is $\frac {3}{365^2}$.  Note that is *slighty* different than the answer above.  This way always for all four of you to share a birthday and the way above specifically states you four do not.

This way is actually not exactly correct. If all four of you have the same birthday I actually counted that possiblity three times instead of just once.